# Rotate entity to view mouse (Craftyjs)

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I've been trying to get my player entity to rotate to the mouse however I cannot get the MouseMove event to trigger.

```
Crafty.e("2D, Mouse, Canvas, Color"
   .attr({ w:1000, h:1000, x:0, y:0 })
   .bind('MouseMove', function(e)
   {
         console.log("Mouse Pos:"+ e.x +","+e.y);
        //get hero
         var pos1 = {
           x: e.x,
           y: e.y
         }
         var pos2 = {
           x: player.x,
           y: player.y
         }
         player.rotation = 0;
         player.rotation = -Engine.degree(pos1, pos2);


     })
```

When I replace MouseMove with click or mousedown or any other mouse event, it rotates to the mouse when that event occurs. However it never calls the mousemove function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, it should work. From a preliminary look at the implementation, the `MouseMove` event goes through the same code as other mouse events. I've suggested an alternative below.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CraftyMouseFace](https://github.com/petarov/CraftyMouseFace), a Crafty component [made by the community](http://craftyjs.com/components/):

> This component does the following:
>
> - It finds the angle between given Sprite and mouse position and triggers a Crafty event which holds information about current mouse position and calculated angle in radians and degrees.
> - Determines sprite facing direction.
> - Triggers Crafty events when a mouse buttons is pressed down or released up anywhere on the game screen.

The first feature sounds like what you need.

Let's put the `MouseMoved` event and its event data to test in the following snippet.
 *Move the mouse pointer around and notice how the green rectangle rotates to face the pointer.*

```js
Crafty.init();

Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Color, MouseFace")
    .attr({x: 75, y: 75, w: 60, h: 60})
    .origin("center")
    .color('green')
    .bind("MouseMoved", function(data) {
        this.rotation = data.rad * 180 / Math.PI;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/craftyjs/Crafty/releases/download/0.7.1/crafty-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/petarov/CraftyMouseFace/master/src/craftyMFace.js"></script>
```